# Azure IoT Hub SAS Token doesn't expire

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

- SDK: C#
- Version: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.2.3
- Bug reproduction code:
  Let the following run for 15 minutes or so* and you'll see that sending still succeeds although the token should have expired.

  ```
  var hostName = ...
  var deviceId = ...
  var sasToken = new SharedAccessSignatureBuilder
      {
          Key = sharedAccessKey,
          Target = $"{hostName}/devices/{deviceId}",
          TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
      }
      .ToSignature();

  var authenticationMethod = new DeviceAuthenticationWithToken(deviceId, sasToken);
  var connectionString = IotHubConnectionStringBuilder
      .Create(hostName, authenticationMethod)
      .ToString();
  var deviceClient = DeviceClient
      .CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, TransportType.Mqtt);

  while (true)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow}: Sending");
      var messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{}");
      var message = new Message(messageContent);
      await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  }
  ```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but does that mean that an open connection never expires? Whose fault is this? I would say that the IoT Hub should close the connection when the token expires, right?

* Internally a token seems to be valid for five more minutes, because that's what they define as [`MaxClockSkew`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/device/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client/Common/Security/SharedAccessSignatureConstants.cs). So to save you some time you can set `SharedAccessSignatureBuilder.TimeToLive` to -4.9 minutes and the token should expire within 0.1 minutes.

Comment: This is a bug that has already been reported - at the moment if you use MQTT, the token is checked when the device connects, but the device is not disconnected by IoT Hub when the token expires.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you provide a link to the issue? So you mean when using e.g. AMQP you don't have this problem?

Comment: I don't have a public link to the issue. I just tried with AMQP and got an authorization error when the SAS expired, same happens with HTTP. So the problem only exists with MQTT protocol currently.

Comment: Bug is still active for package version Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.5.0. Here is the bug's URL:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/163   

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has already been reported - at the moment if you use MQTT, the token is checked when the device connects, but the device is not disconnected by IoT Hub when the token expires. 
I don't have a public link to the issue. I just tried with AMQP and got an authorization error when the SAS expired, same happens with HTTP. So the problem only exists with MQTT protocol currently.